# What is the value of SP2016 Feature Packs? I don't have Software Assurance

Tags: feature, service-pack

I've been asked to build a case for why we need the Feature Packs for SharePoint 2016 as we didn't originally budget for Software Assurance.  Since there has not been one yet (that I know of) for SP2016 On-Prem, I don't know what it will mean if we don't get them.  For instance, is the New SP Framework a part of a Feature Pack?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

Features that are, and are not part of the Feature Packs has yet to be publically released. That said, I would suggest exploring Software Assurance if you're able to.